# ssh/scp into same gateway name but different port

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to ssh from one server
`user@same_gateway -p some_port`
into another server
`user@same_gateway -p another_port`
but it doesnt seem to work, it displays nothing.

Is this due to use of same gateway name? I can connect to the second server fine with local machine.

Main thing i am trying to do is scp but ssh seems like the same issue

Comment: So, you are daisy chaining SSH sessions? After you log on to server 1, and from server 1 you try to logon to server 2, but via the same external gateway? If yes, that often will not work, it depends on the gateway/router.

Comment: The gateway is for external traffic. Use your internal IP addresses for connection within your network.